# Are those getters and setters pure style preference or do they differ in some way? which one is "the best"?

Tags: c++

Whilst learning C++ I've come across different styles of getters and I would like to know if this is just a pure style preference or if they truly differ from eachother in some way at any level.

```
#pragma once
#include "Student.h"
#include <vector>

class StudentPool {
private:
    //We have some variable
    //Edit: removed const from the variable. Those were the Java conventions crossing my mind ^^ 
    std::vector vec;
    
public: 
    //and different "styles?" of getters
    //for example, I've come across this one
    auto get_pool() -> std::vector&;
    //or alternitively as non reference
    auto get_pool() -> std::vector;
    //Added as suggested
    auto get_pool() & -> std::vector;

    /*
    now that I am seeing this, why do they use auto instead of just using the appropriate type?
    more likely why is the trailing style even a thing when we can just declare a usual getter?
    */

    //the standard java-ish one (going to use java naming conventions)
    std::vector getPool();
    
    //So there obviously are a few more styles and ways do declare a getter.  
    //Do you prefer trailing type or the legacy one? What's the advantages and the disadvantages?
};
```

So, I would now like to know which style you would prefer for it's particular use and why and maybe what you use in your projects.

Comment: No, they're doing differen things, and have big consquences how the private data is exposed from your class.

Comment: (3) will not compile at all, did you mean `auto get_pool() & -> std::vector`? *"why do they use auto"* You must use it when using a trailing return type, in this case it doesn't do anything. *"why is the trailing style even a thing"* It can be useful in some template-related scenarios, but here it doesn't change anything. Somebody probably just likes how it looks.

Comment: Actually that one was from my old c++ textbook. Someone might've done a mistake in the book, not entirely sure. I can edit the post.

Comment: The best getter is no getter. A good class is defined by what it does, not what it has.

Comment: What would be the way to access variables then? I've seen endless discussions between people preferring getters/setters and people preferring making the fields public.

Comment: `std::vector` cannot be used without a template parameter i this way

Comment: edited the post, those again were some of my java conventions.

Comment: C++ is not Java. Many Java developers experience major problems learning C++ because the syntax is very similar, yet the language is radically different on multiple fundamental levels. Things just don't work in C++ the way they do in Java. The best advice for any Java developer who's learning C++ is to completely forget everything they know about Java, and start on Chapter 1 of their C++ textbook. What's asked here covers quite a bit of advanced territory that C++ developers don't normally don't deal with until 1-2 years after starting to learn C++.

Comment: That is absolutely correct. Due to the java conventions that are just stuck in my brain I am experiencing major issues getting the proper C++ syntax down. I was just curious because I would like to get rid of bad habbits and start off in this language with writing as good code as possible and in my opinion this is important to be aware of. That obviously is a big goal which will take a while to achieve but I hope to improve my code within the next time.

Comment: "getters/setters" is another Java habit . A private variable with getter/setter is just an obfuscated public variable in many cases. Or in the scenario of this question's code, it's not really clear why the vector would be exposed as a whole (I would instead expect pool management functions that operate on the private vector).  I would say it's uncommon for me to have getter/setter in real code; one example would be at the user interface stage where a user-input field needs to be validated and stored and later retrieved to update the interface

Comment: So you would say for usual and if there isn't some kind of validation logic fields would be declared as **public** if they have to be accessible from outside?

Comment: Well, that's what `public` is for. In that respect there is no difference between Java and C++. Now, what you call a "standard" method, a.k.a. `std::vector getPool();`: what that will do is make a very expensive duplicate copy of the entire vector, return the duplicate object, most likely to be immediately discarded by the caller. That's because of the fundamental differences between Java and C++, and it's more productive to focus on understanding and learning those, then worrying about "style preferences".

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with access modifiers but, wouldn't this `auto get_pool() -> std::vector&;` be used to return a reference to the object instead of copying the whole thing? When i said 'standard' I was rather talking about the java standards.